# create binary random matrix with probability in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, probability

I am new to python. I want to write a function which generates a random `nxm` binary matrix with each value 0 for probability p.

What I did.

```
def randbin(M,N,P):              # function to generate random binary matrix    
    mat = (np.random.rand(M,N)>=P).astype(int)
    return mat  

y = randbin(5,4,0.3)
```

Every time I print the output, I  didn't get the result as per the estimated probability. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see the problem with your method... A better way to generate a random matrix of 0s and 1s with a probability P of 0s is to use `random.choice`:

```
def randbin(M,N,P):  
    return np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(M,N), p=[P, 1-P])
```

To better understand, have a look at the [`random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) documentation.

Comment: If it works, please don't forget to mark the post as answered by ticking the checkmark on the left of my answer (and welcome to stack)

Comment: Does the size is always  a tuple. for example i wanted to create a binary matrix of size 100 in the above function. i.e. np.random.choice([0,1],size = (100). then it gave me an error:  only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalar

Comment: tuples are for matrices. For a 100x100 matrix, use `size=(100, 100)`. For an array of 100 elements, use `size=100` or `size=(100,)`.

Comment: Sometimes this won't work. I get equal `0`'s & `1`'s sometimes though I give unequal probability.

Comment: This is exactly what a probability will do ! When you flip a coin 10 times, you can have 10 faces, it happens. You need to read about probabilities if this behaviour troubles you.